# Position relative fixed div alignment. Why?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I had a problem sizing two divs to fill the entire width of the page with no overlap using percentages (60% width and 3% right margin on one, and 37% on another that was absolutely positioned). I simplified my problem into a jsFiddle and actually fixed it. I had two tests in which the only difference is that the parent has position:relative set.

Why did this fix my problem? I remember having to do such a solution when you need a position:absolute element to position itself absolutely relative to it's parent but I didn't question enough as to what happens and why this works.

Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vajzyqe6/

Here's the css

```
#test1, #test2
{
    width:80%;
}
.type1
{
    background-color:#FFAAAA;
    margin-right:3%;
    margin-left:auto;
    width:60%;
}
.type2
{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#AAFFAA;
    width:37%;
}
#test2
{
    position:relative;   
}
#test2 > div.type1
{
    background-color:#AAAAFF;    
}
#test2 > div.type2
{
    background-color:#FFFFAA;
}
```

Here's the html

```
<div id="test1">
    Test1
    <div class="type1">Type 1</div>
    <div class="type2">Type 2</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="test2">
    Test2
    <div class="type1">Type 1</div>
    <div class="type2">Type 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Why does this happen?` Why does **what** happen? How did you want to fill the page? Question is too ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use percentage height or width in css it will set to the percentage of the first `position : relative` parent.
here your direct parent is at 80% so if it's set to absolute your children divs will set to 60% and 37% of 100% that's why they overlap, now if the parent is set to relative the children will set to 60% and 37% of the 80% and so no overlap

Comment: Is there any reason that it chooses to use the first position relative element versus just the first parent?

Comment: Css works that way :), no but the reason is the the element is only really contained in it's parent with a relative position, if you use margins or top, left, bottom, right you can move it out of it's absolute parent but it will still be in it's parent with relative position

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear but here is the answer anyway.

In the first exemple, `.type1` will be 60% of the body, because it is relative.

In the second exemple, `.type1`will be 60% of `#test2` (which is 80% of the body) because that's what you set when you add the `position: relative` the the parent.

In short: `absolute` element will be sized and positioned depending on the closest `relative` parent.